# xmlhttp.send throws exception while using manifest file

Tags: ajax, caching, google-chrome, safari, manifest

I have a weird problem on Chrome and MobileSafari (works great on IE9)

I have the following code:
var products;

```
function init()
    {
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
              {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
              }
            else
              {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }

            xmlhttp.open("GET","ipad/products.php",false);
            xmlhttp.send();
            products = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            //alert(products.products[0].title);
            getProduct(1);
    }
```

init is called by body onload function.

In addition, I use manifest to cache some files:

```
<HTML manifest="manifest.php">
```

now, when I visit the page for the first time - everything works great.
after a refresh xmlhttp.send() throws "NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101"

in order to view the page normally again I need to clean the browser cache

removing the manifest file solves the problem but I need it for offline browsing.

anyone knows what is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

well, I solved the problem by adding the following line to manifest.php:

NETWORK:
*

now everything works
I guees that the main page was cached too and that caused some problems.
on IE it works because it doesn't support manifest files

Comment: I had http://* and https://* on two separate lines. Addding the lone star "*" on it's own line made ajax work again.